# Python Passing List or Numpy Array

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I wonder if anyone has an elegant solution to being able to pass a python list, a numpy vector (shape(n,)) or a numpy vector (shape(n,1)) to a function.  The idea would be to generalize a function such that any of the three would be valid without adding complexity.

Initial thoughts:

```
1) Use a type checking decorator function and cast to a standard representation.
2) Add type checking logic inline (significantly less ideal than #1).
3) ?
```

I do not generally use python builtin array types, but suspect a solution to this question would also support those.

Comment: You realise you can just do it? Python is dynamically typed, you don't have to specify parameter types.

Comment: sounds to me you answered your own question: yes, option 1

Comment: Since all of the types support iterating and getting items by index, I would just use Duck typing. You can simply treat it as a list.

Comment: @Wolph if he uses numpy arrays, then he most likely wants to avoid explicitly iterating over the arrays

Comment: @shx2, I suppose your right. In that case I would like to quote Knuth: "Premature optimization is the root of all evil (or at least most of it) in programming.". If he still needs it, indeed... option 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert the three types to a "canonical" type, which is a 1dim array, using:

```
arr = np.asarray(arr).ravel()
```

Put in a decorator:

```
import numpy as np
import functools

def takes_1dim_array(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def f(arr, *a, **kw):
        arr = np.asarray(arr).ravel()
        return func(arr, *a, **kw)
    return f
```

Then:

```
@takes_1dim_arr
def func(arr):
   print arr.shape
```

Comment: very nice.  Spot on re: not wanting to iterate as well.  I was leaning in the decorator direction, but did not want to miss a trivial solutions with something that I convinced myself was clean.

Answer (score 3):

I think the simplest thing to do is to start off your function with [`numpy.atleast_2d`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.atleast_2d.html). Then, all 3 of your possibilities will be converted to the `x.shape == (n, 1)` case, and you can use that to simplify your function.

For example,

```
def sum(x):
    x = np.atleast_2d(x)
    return np.dot(x, np.ones((x.shape[0], 1)))
```

`atleast_2d` returns a view on that array, so there won't be much overhead if you pass in something that's already an `ndarray`. However, if you plan to modify `x` and therefore want to make a copy instead, you can do `x = np.atleast_2d(np.array(x))`.

Comment: This works, but it is messy in the case of many functions - quite a bit of code duplication that a decorator avoids.